# IIS says: You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL)

Tags: iis

Yeah, I know. It's been asked like 100 times before. But most of those questions ask about ASP.NET pages, or they've created a website and for the first time, they can't access their websites.

I have a local website (on my laptop) that has beein working for like 3 months now, and **all of a sudden** today it can't serve a simple CSS file, and gives me this error.

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

That's what drives me crazy. I haven't changed anything.

These are things that I've tried:

- Changing the application pool user to administrator (the most
  powerful user) and testing authorization of the corresponding website
  (which is all green now). But still no success.
- Giving explicit full control permissions to **Everyone** on styles
  folder, still no result
- I've checked the files to see if they're being encrypted by a virus or something, but they're all OK.
- The style file is just simply on the drive the website is. It's not located on a network share or UNC, therefore not related to that.
- I've checked the ACL on the file and the container folder to see if a user is being denied to access explicitly. Nothing is changed there. Everything is just the way it was before.
- I checked advanced properties of the file, and no encryption or compression option is selected.
- I created a simple `index.html` file in the same directory, and it works. So, there should be no general problem in IIS. I also created a simple `index.css` file, and it works too. They're siblings to the original style.

Any help can prevent me from going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try:

- Run Process Monitor and filter for the file in question
- Run Failed Request Tracing in IIS
- Run chkdsk on the drive the file is located on.
- Copy the content of the file into a new file, delete the old file, rename the new file to the old name.